# Is there a normal practice to loop through redis?

Tags: node.js, database, optimization, redis, node-redis

I am using redis as my temporary storage which I fill in with hSet keys.
I need to store only active session which were updated less than 10min ago. I decided to go through all of the keys with background worker every 10min to insert inactive sessions to my main PostgreSQL and delete it from the redis one. As I know "EXPIRE" isn't working for me, cause I need to save my sessions before erasing.

I am using node "redis" package and my avg payload to redis is about **50 000 active sessions**.
Is it the only way to solve my problem:

```
for await (const key of connection.scanIterator()) {
    const data = await connection.hGetAll(key);
    if (is10MinutesHasPast(data)) {
        // insert data to postgres
        await connection.delete(key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the SQL right behind https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync/tree/master/examples/postgres
with Redis Gears that can do something similar